# Remove duplicates from array of non-equatable objects

Tags: array, swift

I have an array of non-`Equatable` objects. I want to remove all the duplicates from the array.

```
class SearchResult { // non-equatable
    var index: Int!
    var score: Int!

    init(_ index: Int, score: Int = 0) { 
        self.index = index 
        self.score = score
    }
}
var searchResults: [SearchResult] = [SearchResult(0), SearchResult(1), SearchResult(1), SearchResult(2), SearchResult(2)]
```

`searchResults.map { $0.index }` gives us: `0, 1, 1, 2, 2`

Currently, I do so by mapping the objects' property `index`, which is equatable, since it's an `Int`. This way, I can remove the duplicates from the indices array:

```
let withDupes: [SearchResult] = searchResults
let indices = withDupes.map { $0.index }.removingDuplicates()
```

---

For reference, `.removingDuplicates()` comes from [a post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35014912/3397217)

---

**Note: this is the part I want to be reviewed.**

Then, I get the object with the corresponding index by looping through the indices array and add it to the `noDupes` array.

```
var noDupes: [SearchResult] = []
indices.forEach { (index) in
    guard let notADupe = (withDupes.filter { $0.index == index }).first else { return }
    noDupes.append(notADupe)
}
```

`noDupes.map { $0.index }` now is: `0, 1, 2`

Now, this code works, but it will be executed very often. Since I feel like this is not a very efficient way to remove the duplicates, I fear a performance drop.
How can I improve and / or simplify my code and still successfully remove the duplicates from the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that there is no need to make the `SearchResult` properties (implicitly unwrapped) optionals, as they are always initialized:

```
class SearchResult { // non-equatable
    var index: Int
    var score: Int

    init(_ index: Int, score: Int = 0) {
        self.index = index
        self.score = score
    }
}
```

Your approach is indeed not optimal, after determining a unique set of property
values, the original array must be searched for each value separately. This lookup can be improved slightly by using `first(where:)`

```
var noDupes: [SearchResult] = []
indices.forEach { (index) in
    guard let notADupe = withDupes.first(where: { $0.index == index }) else { return }
    noDupes.append(notADupe)
}
```

The advantage of `first(where:)` over `filter + first` is that it short-circuits and does not create an intermediate array.

But a better and faster solution would be to modify the `removingDuplicates()`
method so that it compares the array elements according to a given *key* (which is
then required to be `Equatable`).

Here is a possible implementation, using the [“Smart KeyPath”](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md#smart-keypaths-better-key-value-coding-for-swift) feature
from Swift 4:

```
extension Array {
    func removingDuplicates<T: Equatable>(byKey key: KeyPath<Element, T>)  -> [Element] {
        var result = [Element]()
        var seen = [T]()
        for value in self {
            let key = value[keyPath: key]
            if !seen.contains(key) {
                seen.append(key)
                result.append(value)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

This can then simply be used as

```
let searchResults: [SearchResult] = [SearchResult(0), SearchResult(1), SearchResult(1), SearchResult(2), SearchResult(2)]

let withoutDuplicates = searchResults.removingDuplicates(byKey: \.index)
```

It might also be worth to add another specialization for the case that the key is
`Hashable` (as it is in your example) because then the `seen` array can be replaced by a set,
which improves the lookup speed from `O(N)` to `O(1)`:

```
extension Array {
    func removingDuplicates<T: Hashable>(byKey key: KeyPath<Element, T>)  -> [Element] {
        var result = [Element]()
        var seen = Set<T>()
        for value in self {
            if seen.insert(value[keyPath: key]).inserted {
                result.append(value)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Note that `if seen.insert(key).inserted` does the “test and insert if not present” with a single call.

Another (more flexible) option is to pass a closure to the function which determines
the uniquing key for each element:

```
extension Array {
    func removingDuplicates<T: Hashable>(byKey key: (Element) -> T)  -> [Element] {
        var result = [Element]()
        var seen = Set<T>()
        for value in self {
            if seen.insert(key(value)).inserted {
                result.append(value)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let withoutDuplicates = searchResults.removingDuplicates(byKey: { $0.index })
```

Comment: Hey, this looks awesome. Thanks so far! I'm getting an error on `.removingDuplicates(byKey: \.index)` saying `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. Is the backslash intended or is that a typo?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth: That is intentional. But it requires that you make the properties non-optional.

Comment: Ahh, removing the `!` did the job, thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity: would it technically be possible to implement this for optionals, though?

Comment: Also, is there any performance difference between `removingDuplicates<T: Equatable>(byKey:)` and my approach?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth: I don't know if the key paths work for implicitly unwrapped optionals. I have added another option (passing a closure) which is more flexible and that would work with an IUO as well. – The `removingDuplicates<T: Equatable>` should be faster because it traverses the array only once, whereas your solution traverses the array again for each key.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for this great answer. I'd like to give you way more upvotes. Cheers!

Comment: Both of these implementations can be tidied up substantially with `filter`: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/fbba1e58c91fbd4b5b767bcf8586112b

Comment: @Alexander: Yes, that is nice and very concise. I am not sure if I would prefer a closure with side-effects, the loop might be easier to understand. But that is a matter of taste.

Comment: Surely a filter with side effects is a lesser sin than reinventing the `filter` wheel

Comment: @Alexander: Actually I should have known about that approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42542237/1187415 :)

Comment: @MartinR We've all been there hah https://stackoverflow.com/a/40579948/3141234

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorthand solution using `reduce` so that you don't need the for-loop.

```
let items = itemsWithDuplicates.reduce([]) { array, item in !array.contains(where: { $0.index == item.index }) ?  array + [item] : array }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: Thanks, @TobySpeight. For a moment I thought this was stack overflow. I did a quick re-write of the explanation and will do a re-read of your terms soon.